# LibGDX Angle/Rotation Issue

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) map editor to create a simple tiled map. Within my map I have several rectangles, if I create a rectangle with a width of 50 and height of 10 and rotate it exactly 90°, save the map and load it up in my [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) project, the shape is rendered correctly - however if I use a random angle, let's say 26° for example and I render the map again, I do not get the desired result, in fact I get the **exact** opposite desired angle.

I'm reading the Tiled map float directly from the map using:

```
 Map map = new TmxMapLoader().load(mapLocation + mapName + mapExtension);
 for (MapLayer mapLayer : map.getLayers()) {
     for (MapObject mapObject : mapLayer.getObjects() {
          MapProperties objectProperties = mapObject.getProperties();

          float objectRotation = objectProperties.get("rotation") != null ? Float.parseFloat(objectProperties.get("rotation").toString)) : 0.0f;
          objectRotation = MathUtils.degRad * objectRotation;
     }
 }
```

The `MathUtils.degRad` converts the degrees read directly from the map properties into radians, but somewhere along the line there's a misread happening or I've completely missed something.

Later, I create my bodyDef and set its angle to the above mentioned `objectRotation` using `bodyDef.angle = objectRotation` followed by creating my body with default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a bit of math.

`MathUtils.cosDeg( angleInDegrees )
MathUtils.sinDeg ( angleInDegrees )`